# Mysql query to get detail of comma-separated ids data

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, items and members :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
`id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`member` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

What if, for example I have a record inside `items`, such as

```
INSERT INTO  `test`.`items` (
`id` ,
`name` ,
`member`
)
VALUES (
NULL ,  'xxxx',  '1, 2, 3'
);
```

in `members` :

```
INSERT INTO `members` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'asdf'),
(2, 'qwert'),
(3, 'uiop'),
(4, 'jkl;');
```

and I'd like to display `items.member` data with `members.name`, something like `1#asdf, 2#qwert, 3#uiop`??

I've tried the following query,

```
SELECT items.id, items.name, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('#', members.id, members.name) ) as member

FROM `items` 
LEFT JOIN members AS members on (members.id = items.member)
WHERE items.id = 1
```

But the result is not like I expected. Is there any other way to display the data via one call query? Because I'm using PHP, right now, i'm explode `items.member` and loop it one by one, to display the `members.name`.

Comment: Can you show us your `item` table?

Comment: Can you change the schema of your database?

Comment: @bonCodigo my `items` table is just contain one record, like above

Comment: @thorn the one described by eggyal (+1 to his answer).

Comment: @kmkaplan agree.. It solved my pain. Thank you, anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look into using [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) in your join criteria:

```
FROM items JOIN members ON FIND_IN_SET(members.id, items.member)
```

However, note from the definition of `FIND_IN_SET()`:

> A string list is a string composed of substrings separated by “`,`” characters.

Therefore the `items.member` column should not contain any spaces (I suppose you could use `FIND_IN_SET(members.id, REPLACE(items.member, ' ', ''))` - but this is going to be extremely costly as your database grows).

Really, you *should* [normalise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your schema:

```
CREATE TABLE memberItems (
  item_id   INT(5) NOT NULL,
  member_id INT(5) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY   item_id REFERENCES   items (id),
  FOREIGN KEY member_id REFERENCES members (id)
);

INSERT INTO memberItems
  (item_id, member_id)
SELECT items.id, members.id
FROM   items
  JOIN members ON FIND_IN_SET(members.id, REPLACE(items.member,' ',''))
;

ALTER TABLE items DROP member;
```

This is both index-friendly (and therefore can be queried very efficiently) and has the database enforce referential integrity.
Then you can do:

```
FROM items JOIN memberItems ON memberItems.item_id = items.id
           JOIN members     ON members.id = memberItems.member_id
```

Note also that it's generally unwise to use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to combine separate records into a string in this fashion: your application should instead be prepared to loop over the resultset to fetch each member.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Indeed, the normal database, should be like `memberItems`. But, because this is not normal, so I'm trying to find a way to make this thing happen. FYI, I have 1k line `items` in real, that it will take some time if I have to split it. I'll deepen the ref.

Comment: @thom: See my edit above, which shows automatic population of `memberItems` from your existing data.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this sample:

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99ce5/1)

Your query seems to work for what you have mentioned in the question... :)

```
SELECT I.ID, I.ITEM,
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("#",M.ID,
M.NAME, " ")) AS MEMB

FROM ITEMS AS I
LEFT JOIN MEMBERS AS M
ON M.ID = I.MID
WHERE i.id = 1
;
```

**EDITTED ANSWER**
This query will not work for you¬ as your schema doesn't seem to have any integrity... or proper references. Plus your memeber IDs are delimtted by a comma, which has been neglected in this answer.

Comment: The `items` table in your sqlfiddle is completely different to that given in the question, which has a `member` column containing a string (apparently) of member IDs delimited by commas...

Comment: @eggyal +1 for yours. I figured it out with a surprise when you pointed that he is adding member ID as into items as a comma delimitted string.....mine only works for normalize situations...